# How to loop a nested array with object and convert it to a new array with the same structure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

I have an array with object like below:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1013,
        "code": "CAT1",
        "name": "TOP 1",
        "level": 1,
        "sub_categories": [
            {
                "id": 1016,
                "code": "SUB1",
                "name": "Child 1",
                "level": 2,
                "sub_categories": [
                    {
                        "id": 1017,
                        "code": "SUB11",
                        "name": "Child 2",
                        "level": 3,
                        "sub_categories": [
                            {
                                "id": 1018,
                                "code": "SUB111",
                                "name": "Child 3",
                                "level": 4,
                                "sub_categories": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 1019,
                                        "code": "SUB21",
                                        "name": "Child 4",
                                        "level": 5,
                                        "sub_categories": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1014,
        "code": "CAT2",
        "name": "TOP 2",
        "level": 1,
        "sub_categories": [
            {
                "id": 1020,
                "code": "SUB22",
                "name": "Child 1",
                "level": 2,
                "sub_categories": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1015,
        "code": "CAT3",
        "name": "TOP 3",
        "level": 1,
        "sub_categories": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2027,
        "code": "TOP4",
        "name": "TOP 4",
        "level": 1,
        "sub_categories": []
    }
]
```

I want to replace all the `id` with `key`, all the `name` with `title`, and all the `sub_categories` with `children` in the above array and return a new array with object like below:

```
[
    {
        "key": 1013,
        "code": "CAT1",
        "title": "TOP 1",
        "level": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "key": 1016,
                "code": "SUB1",
                "title": "Child 1",
                "level": 2,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "key": 1017,
                        "code": "SUB11",
                        "title": "Child 2",
                        "level": 3,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "key": 1018,
                                "code": "SUB111",
                                "title": "Child 3",
                                "level": 4,
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "key": 1019,
                                        "code": "SUB21",
                                        "title": "Child 4",
                                        "level": 5,
                                        "children": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": 1014,
        "code": "CAT2",
        "title": "TOP 2",
        "level": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "key": 1020,
                "code": "SUB22",
                "title": "Child 1",
                "level": 2,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": 1015,
        "code": "CAT3",
        "title": "TOP 3",
        "level": 1,
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "key": 2027,
        "code": "TOP4",
        "title": "TOP 4",
        "level": 1,
        "children": []
    }
]
```

Anyone knows how to convert it?

Comment: Use a recursive function.

Comment: Can you show the code? @Barmar